# Firebase Listener slow after network switch

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android application that uses Firebase. Database listeners `onDataChange` methods are called quickly at first.

I leave the app, switch the network connection (wifi -> data or data -> wifi). I make sure there is still internet access, and return to the app, listeners now take a long time to respond (more than a minute) and as a result my app hangs.

```
reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            // Takes forever
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            // Takes forever
        }
    });
```

Any idea what could be going on here?

**EDIT TO CLARIFY**: I switched networks, verified internet connectivity and then returned to the app and executed the code above. It's like Firebase was somehow disconnected during the switch.

Comment: About how long is your device offline during the change in connectivity that causes a more than a minute delay?

Comment: I am just switching networks, I suppose there would be a moment when it is offline?

Comment: How are you doing the switch? Can you please tell in detail as `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` executes `onDataChange` method immediately and after executing that method once, it stops listening....

Comment: If you're switching networks, there will definitely be a moment when the app is "offline", and the existing websocket used by the Firebase SDK is disconnected.

Comment: I've made an edit to clarify. I am attaching the listener after switching connections and verifying connectivity. `onDataChange` will not fire.

Comment: The easiest way to see what Firebase is doing during/after the switch is to [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check logcat.